# Why does my css-animation extend beyond the window?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, velocity

I have made a CSS-animation with Velocity.js:

https://codepen.io/blaustern_fotografie/pen/GvxWoW

The code is designed such that the circles are not allowed to go beyond the window on the left and right side. The function "my_animate" is responsible for this:

```
function my_animate(circle) {

var new_y = Math.floor(
  Math.random() * ((height -50)-50)+50
);

var new_x = Math.floor(
  Math.random() * ((width-50)-50)+50
);

var r = Math.random();
//var nd = Math.floor(r * 500 - 250);

$(circle).velocity(
  {
    translateX: new_x-$(circle).position().left,
    translateY: new_y-$(circle).position().top,
    //translateZ: nd,
    opacity: r,
    blur: Math.round((1 - r) * 5)
  },
  {
    duration: Math.round(Math.random() * 10000 + 10000),
    complete: function() {
      my_animate(circle);
    }
  }
);
}
```

Does anyone know why the circles are passing the edges?

Comment: Solution: My corrected version with comments can be found here:
https://codepen.io/blaustern_fotografie/pen/GvxWoW

Comment: On of my errors: translateX takes the new x-position, not the distance to the position

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems here in calculating the new position.

The use of `Math.random()` is leading to random values being generated for `new_x`.

```
var new_x = Math.floor(
  Math.random() * ((width -50)-50)+50
);
```

Then `new_x-$(circle).position().left` is leading to values being generated which are out of window range.

You should normalise your randomiser to generate new position such that the values generated are always between the min and max points on the viewport.

Comment: The variable width refers to window.innerWidth. I logged the values of new_x and they are always in the range [50, width-50]

Comment: 50-470= - 420 --> so I think the circle should move 420 px to the left ??

Comment: Your formulae: `new_x-$(circle).position().left` is leading to values which are out of range. Eg: If viewport is from 0 to 500. currentPosition = 470 and new_x = 50 then new position = -420 which is out of range

Comment: But translateX is an offset and not the new x-Position. So the circle should move 420px to the left until it reaches the position x=50...

Comment: Try this fiddle out: Have added a few console logs so that you can see why the ball is moving out of range: https://codepen.io/yesha-shah/pen/XYZvXV?editors=0011

Comment: no in this case IMO it will move 490px to the right because 490 is positive not negative...

Comment: Thank you very much  I will look closely at it later

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Math.random in range of your window.width, otherwise the randomizer will just calculate values out of your window.width.

Comment: The variable width refers to window.innerWidth. I logged the values of new_x and they are always in the range [50, width-50]